# Plotting via geopandas but only one point shows. What's wrong with my code? Map and points are in same projection

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, geopandas, shapely

Will appreciate any help. Been stuck at this for two weeks and have tried already solutions online. Am using Python 3.8.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r'path')
df = pd.read_csv('emscPhilippines2008to2020.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=0, low_memory=False)
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['Longitude'], df['Latitude'])]
crs = "epsg:32651"
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
basemap = gpd.read_file('PH_provs.shp')
gdf.plot() # POINTS ONLY
gdf.plot(ax=basemap.plot(figsize=(17,15)), marker='o', color='red', markersize=15);
```

Both are in EPSG:32651. Even if the CSV is imported in 4326, same result.

Result

[image]

Points only

[image]

Comment: They are not in the same projection, look at coordinates along the plots.

Comment: How can that happen? I checked both the map and points' CRS in the console and both came out 32651. I'll try using a fresh basemap shp. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Redownloading the basemap shp worked. Thanks!